# Changing div positions with matchMedia on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I've two containers that move with a media query. When they move I use matchMedia to fire an event that causes a div to be moved from one container to the other.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dKRZWY?editors=1111)

The problem comes when I refresh the page. The css media query works, but matchMedia only works when the query changes. If you reload the codepen at under 1000px width you'll see the problem.

I've had a search and read of a few answers, but I'm new to JS and wary of what I should and shouldn't call (especially when it comes to listening for size changes).

Should I just use enquire.js? I've read that it doesn't have this problem. Or is there an easy fix?

```
<header>

  <div class="container" id="container1">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item" id="moveMe">2</div>
    <div class="item" id="item3">3</div>

  </div>

  <div class="container" id="container2">
    <div class="item" id="item4">4</div>
  </div>

</header>
```

css

```
header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #eaeaea;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px){
  header{
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  padding: 2rem;
}

#container1{
  background: red;
}

#container2{
  background: blue;
}

.item{
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 2rem;
  background: white;

}
```

js

```
var container1 = document.getElementById('container1');
var container2 = document.getElementById('container2');
var moveMe = document.getElementById('moveMe');
var item3 = document.getElementById('item3');
var item4 = document.getElementById('item4');


matchMedia("(max-width: 1000px)").addListener(function(mql){
  if(mql.matches){
    container2.insertBefore(moveMe, item4);
  } else {
    container1.insertBefore(moveMe, item3);
  }
})
```

*edit: RE i.terrible's suggestion I tried to split up the code so I could run it on window.onload.

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1000px)").addListener(checkMedia);

window.onload = checkMedia(mql);

function checkMedia(mql){ 
    if(mql.matches){
      container2.insertBefore(moveMe, item4);
    } else {
      container1.insertBefore(moveMe, item3);
    }
}
```

it didn't work though...

*edit2: Ah...this works. I messed up above.

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1000px)");

checkMedia(mql);
mql.addListener(checkMedia);

function checkMedia(mql){ 
    if(mql.matches){
      container2.insertBefore(moveMe, item4);
    } else {
      container1.insertBefore(moveMe, item3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand you correctly. You'd like to react to changes in the screen width. To do that, bind the media query to a resize listener like this:

```
    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
        <your mq-code here>
    });
```

If you want the MQ to fire when the page loads, also run it on load as well:

```
window.onload = <your code>
```

In any case it would be better to refactor your media query to a separate function.
Please ask, if I should elaborate.

Comment: thanks for the reply - the code is reacting to screen size changes at the moment using matchMedia and the listener. what i'm not sure of is how to implement the window.onload = <my code> statement - because <my code> is tied up in the anonymous function and listener (if that makes sense!)

Comment: i managed to split it up. i've edited the code in the original post. i've not used `window.onload`, i just ran my function instead - which I assume amounts to the same thing?

Comment: Yes it does - glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var container1 = document.getElementById('container1');
var container2 = document.getElementById('container2');
var moveMe = document.getElementById('moveMe');
var item3 = document.getElementById('item3');
var item4 = document.getElementById('item4');

var mql = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1000px)");

checkMedia(mql);
mql.addListener(checkMedia);

function checkMedia(mql){ 
    if(mql.matches){
      container2.insertBefore(moveMe, item4);
    } else {
      container1.insertBefore(moveMe, item3);
    }
}
```